# plink - how to exit SSH session?

Tags: linux, ssh, powershell, plink

I have one linux machine with ssh enabled. I used plink on another machine (windows) to connect to my linux machine. After successfully connecting, I just exited power shell console and now I don't know how to access linux terminal (which appears automatically after connecting).

I checked on linux machine, and it says that I'm still connected. 
How do I kill SSH session from powershell and how can I access terminal again (from powershell)?

Comment: `plink` is not intended for interactive use. // You could always just kill the process.

Comment: How do i kill the process?

Comment: If you are running plink then at the end of your command, create a new line and use the command `EXIT` and that should do it. So to recap, run the usual `plink` commands, and be sure the last command to run once the logic is complete is a new line of `EXIT`. Otherwise if the logic reaches the end of the file, it'll end that way too but using a simple `EXIT` command should do the trick; that's how I do it.

Comment: I was using plink interactive session and after exiting powershell console, session remained active.